# PTIJ: Is Super Mario Odyssey a Basar B'Chalav issue?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

For background: [Super Mario Odyssey](https://www.mariowiki.com/Super_Mario_Odyssey) is a well-received 3D platformer put out by Nintendo in October 2017. In the game, the titular plumber must travel the world to chase Bowser to prevent his marriage to Princess Peach, alongside his new sidekick Cappy.

One of the places he visits is called the [Luncheon Kingdom](https://www.mariowiki.com/Luncheon_Kingdom), an Italy-inspired food-themed land. The Kingdom is known best for its [Stupendous Stew](https://www.mariowiki.com/Stupendous_Stew), a vegetable dish which, when Mario first reaches it, can be seen to have contained both several blocks of cheese and a slab of meat.

Is there an issue of benefiting of Basar B'chalav by playing this game? What about if you play the game, but you never complete that particular level, so that the meat is never put into the pot?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: It's not an issue of basar v'chalav as far as I know, but you might not want to play the game because moshav leitzim

Comment: @ezra Party pooper. I refuse to see such a serious comment in a Purim Torah thread.

Comment: Sorry to spoil the mood :P

Comment: I’m curious why this was so downvotes. Do people just not like the joke or the fact that it’s asking about a video game?

Comment: I've noticed that a lot of the PT questions have downvotes. :/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is absolutely amazing.  The Ralbag (Devarim 3:1, Toaliyos) says that a person will receive a punishment for playing Mario, and if one doesn't realize that he was hit for playing Mario, he will not accept Mussar for anything:

> התועלת השביעי הוא במידות, **והוא להודיע שהוא ראוי למי (שישיגהו)[שהשיגהו] עונש מהשם יתעלה על מריו**, שיראה שהוא מרגיש שיעור מה שאבד ממנו, כי בזה תועלת ללקיחת המוסר. **כי מי שלא ירגיש שהוכה על מריו לא יקבל מוסר**, כמו שאמר הנביא על מה תוכו עוד תוסיפו סרה וגו׳.

Clearly, it is considered Hanaah from Basar Bechalav, and is a very serious Issur.

Comment: That’s an awesome find. But how do you know that it’s a Basar b’chalav issue? Mario’s been around for over 30 years - maybe it’s for playing any Mario game? Further, from the wording of שהוכה על מריו, I don’t see anything about *playing* it - maybe the Ralbag is commanding us to do a no-damage speedrun of the game, so that we aren’t punished for “hitting Mario.”

Comment: That's a serious question.  We must rely on the fact that it says a lashon of Mario twice, which in Hebrew is ל' מריו מריו, and that the gemartia of that is equal to בשר חלב, therefore we have a Remez that it is referring to this specific issue.

Answer (score 2):

It still may be comparable to eating at seudas achashverosh. Yesh Harbeh Ladun ;)

Comment: I’m not sure I follow.

Comment: Luncheon kingdom....

Comment: If it said Kingdom Luncheon, your diyuk would be correct. Now that it says Luncheon Kingdom... :)

Comment: WOW, IT'S RAV CHAIM KANIYEVSKY!  I didn't know you spoke English or knew what Super Mario is.